# Python, Tkinter, StringVar

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, key

Good evening forum. Let me get help from you. I need to output the key from the dictionary to the terminal, I work through GUI Tkinter and tk.StringVar. For example, there is a pair of 'apple' and 'pineapple', and because of the spelling in the term 'apple' I knocked out 'pineapple'. Help please. Code below!
Sincerely, *Vladimir*!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('Boom')
window.geometry('300x200+50+75')
window.resizable(True, True)

def info():
    print(info)
fruit = {'яблоко':'apple', "ананас":'pineapple'}

mystring = tk.StringVar(window)
def getvalue():
    print(mystring.get())
entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=mystring, bg='white', fg='black', width=200).pack()
button = tk.Button(window, 
    text='Translate',
    bg='blue',
    fg='black', width=15, height=3, command=getvalue).pack()

my_string1 = tk.StringVar(window)
def info():
    print(my_string1())
entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=my_string1, bg='white', fg='black', width=200).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you need it to translate from English to Russian *and* from Russian to English? You could have two dictionaries, one for each.

Comment: Yes, this is for translation. How do you see my code if you use your strategy? What do you need to change in the code? Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: to make code more readable you could put all functions directly after imports - and before `window = tk.Tk()`. Don't mix normal lines with functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for translating from both Russian to English and vice versa:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('Boom')
window.geometry('300x200+50+75')
window.resizable(True, True)

# Create two dictionaries: one for Russian to English, the other for English to Russian
fruit_r_to_e = {'яблоко':'apple', "ананас":'pineapple'}
fruit_e_to_r = {english: russian for russian, english in fruit_r_to_e.items()}

mystring = tk.StringVar(window)
my_string1 = tk.StringVar(window)

def getvalue():
    global mystring, my_string1, fruit_e_to_r, fruit_r_to_e

    string = mystring.get()

    # If the string is in English, translate it to Russian
    if string in fruit_e_to_r:
        print(fruit_e_to_r[string])

    # If the string is in Russian, translate it to English
    elif string in fruit_r_to_e:
        print(fruit_r_to_e[string])

    else:
        print("This word is not in the dictionary.")

def info():
    global my_string1
    print(my_string1())

entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=mystring, bg='white', fg='black', width=200)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(window, 
    text='Translate',
    bg='blue',
    fg='black',
    width=15,
    height=3,
    command=getvalue
)
button.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=my_string1, bg='white', fg='black', width=200)
entry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I created two dictionaries, one for each translation direction. When `getvalue()` is called, it checks if the word is in the English dictionary: `if string in fruit_e_to_r:`, and translates it to Russian if it is. If it isn't, it checks if it is in the Russian dictionary: `elif string in fruit_r_to_e:`, and translates it to English if it is. If it is not in either dictionary: `else:`, it shows a message saying that the word is not in either dictionary.

I made a few other changes to the code as well. I removed the `from tkinter import *`, because you already have tkinter imported in the next line: `import tkinter as tk`, and because wildcard imports (using `from <package> import *`) are discouraged.

I also noticed that when you create the widgets, you call `.pack()` when you assign the widgets to variables, for example you used `entry = tk.Entry(...).pack()`. This is a problem, because the `pack()` method returns `None`, so you won't be able to use the widgets later in the program. You need to call `entry = tk.Entry(...)`, and then call `entry.pack()` on the next line. This way, the `entry` variable actually contains an instance of `tkinter.Entry`, instead of `None`.

You'll notice that I also used the `global` statement in the functions. This is not required (unless you're assigning variables), but it's generally a good idea. `global` tells the function that it's using variables that were defined *outside* the function. So, `global mystring, fruit_e_to_r, fruit_r_to_e` tells `getvalue()` that `mystring`, `fruit_e_to_r`, and `fruit_r_to_e` are all variables that were created *outside* of `getvalue()`.

Comment: quick note: you could use only one dictionary prefilled, the other could be generated in runtime: `fruit_e_to_r = {english: russian for russian, english in fruit_r_to_e.items()}`

Comment: Thank you very much for such a contribution to my development. Very grateful. And how do I make the translated word automatically appear in the second line of "entry" after I click 'Translate'?

Comment: I think you would use `my_string1.set()`. I will update my answer code to do this. Also, @Matiiss, I will use this in my code as well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I will wait for a more updated version of my code. Thank you very much for your help. Goodbye!

Comment: Excuse me, can you reset the version from .set () here so that I can start developing a version for mass use and creating a visual page for this program?